# Can't inherit button color on style

Tags: android, xml, colors

I am trying to define button properties on style.
My code is

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#f37022</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

And using as

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prepaid Package"
        style="@style/button"/>
```

But the color of the button's normal state is not changing.

This button style is only for some buttons. Not for all butons.

What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit after question clarification**

Save you style.xml in res/values/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="custom_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#f37022</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

Apply it like so:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prepaid Package"
    style="@style/custom_button"/>
```

---

**first answer**

You need to inherit the parent style.

```
<style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#f37022</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

That way all your Button's that are not styled will have your custom style. i.e. no need to put in the style value.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prepaid Package"/>
```

Comment: Is that means that `colorButtonNormal` will be applied for all buttons?

Comment: But I don't want to apply this style for all buttons.
I want to apply for this styles for some buttons.

Comment: This color `#f37022` for `colorButtonNormal` appears on `on pressed` state.